# How to evaluate the formula $\lnot(A\land B) \lor \lozenge A$ to true in modal logic?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, modal-logic

I have the claim:

> $\lnot(A\land B) \lor \lozenge A \lor \square\lnot B$

but I can't find any frame/example that evaluates the claim to true.
E.g. According to $\lnot(A\land B)$ I simply could create a frame with an empty relation. But for getting $\lozenge A$ to true I need a frame with a relation to $A$.
In my opinion that is a contradiction, because $\lnot(A\land B)$ means that there must not be any $A$ in the frame whereas $\lozenge A$ means that every transition must contain an $A$.
Can anybody show me an example that evaluates the claim above to true? If possible, it should be an example that is not reflexive.

Comment: Note that $\lnot(A \land B)$ can be true even if $A$ isn't, namely if it happens that $B$ is true.

Comment: By the way can you put in question your understanding of the meanings of diamond and square? Also a brief note on what a "frame" is?

Comment: For a disjunction of three things to hold, only one of the three things needs to hold.

Comment: ... so you don't even need to bother about the $\Diamond A$ and $\Box \neg B$ parts and can just do with the empty frame that satisfies $\neg (A \land B)$ and thereby the entire disjunction, to even further explicify what spaceisdarkgreen said.